# Vim: plugin to change all decimal points?

Tags: formatting

CSV.vim plugin has an ability to change the column deliminator/separator. I would like to find a plugin by which I can change all decimal points (such as comma) to dot, does there exist plugin to do such conversion?

*P.s. This is the command that does this, `:%s/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g`, but I would like to find a plugin that brings this kind of common conversions as scripts.*

Comment: For such a simple command, you don't need a plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you define a command from this line? Drop it in `$HOME/.vim/plugin/yourpluginname.vim`, and you're done. (at least, this is enough for something that simple)

```
command! -range=% ChangeDotToComa <line1>,<line2>s/\d\zs\.\ze\d/,/g
```

PS: Honestly, in that case, I'd rather change the locale of my machine to tell it that I want to use `.` as the decimal point and not `,`. (But then I've troubles with CSV files produced by excel running with unmodified French locale. They are fortunately rare enough)

Comment: For a one liner like this one which isn't defined for a specific filetype, is there a reason to put it in a plugin rather than directly in the vimrc?

Comment: @statox, Good question. Plugins can be easily installed/distributed, and potentially their maintenance can be centralized. For instance, one may want to use the character returned by `locale -k decimal_point`. If this was a distributed plugin, everyone could take advantage of it. Now ... is this the reason why the OP asked for a plugin? I don't know.

Comment: My mistake. I've fixed the path of the file. Files under `$HOME/.vim/plugin` are automatically loaded. Those under `$HOME/.vim/`aren't.

Comment: Does every file.vim in .vim folder get automatically loaded?

Comment: I've answered your question in the comment that precedes it.